# JAVA rest assure get request with auth token

Tags: java, rest

I am trying to create a post request with auth token but I am getting null response. Can you please help me.Can you please let me know what am I missing in the code ?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
         try {
                String url = "https://test.abc.com/";
                    String token="XXXXXX-abcd-496a-ae73-7659587896";
                URL object = new URL(url);
                HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) object.openConnection();
                con.setDoInput(true);
                con.setRequestMethod("GET");
                con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=UTF-8");
                con.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
                con.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Bearer " + token);
                //Display what the GET request returns
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                int HttpResult = con.getResponseCode();
                if (HttpResult == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(
                            new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream(), "utf-8"));
                    String line = null;
                    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                        sb.append(line + "\n");
                    }
                    br.close();
                    System.out.println(con.getResponseMessage());
                } else {
                    System.out.println(con.getResponseMessage());
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println(e);
            }
         }
    }
```

Comment: can you please add error stack trace?

Comment: Debug your code you will find an error for why your data coming null. Or you can give response code or error stack so that we can find the problem easily.

Comment: it is just coming as null